# Проблема с DialogHost

Tags: c#, wpf

Здавствуйте, нужна булевая функция,в которой создается DialogHost c кнопками "OK" и "cancel" на нем,а также с возможностью узнать какая кнопка нажата. Программа ждет нажатия какой-то из кнопок и возвращает true если "OK" и false если "cancel" соответственно.

```cs
public bool Dialog()
        {
            DialogHost Host = new DialogHost { VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch, IsManipulationEnabled = true };
            Grid DialogGrid = new Grid { Width = 450, Height = 120 };
           {
                Button OK = new Button
                {
                    Content = "OK",
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 10),
                    Focusable = false,
                };
                OK.SetResourceReference(Button.StyleProperty, "MaterialDesignFlatButton");
                OK.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 3);
                OK.Click += OK_Click;
                void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)\\При срабатывании обработчика функция Dialog() должна вернуть true
                {
                    Host.IsOpen = false;
                    grid.Children.Remove(Host);
                }
                DialogGrid.Children.Add(OK);
            }
            { 
                Button Cancel = new Button
                {
                    Content = "Cancel",
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right,
                    Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 10, 10),
                    Focusable = false,
                };
                Cancel.SetResourceReference(Button.StyleProperty, "MaterialDesignFlatButton");
                Cancel.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 3);
                Cancel.Click += Cancel_Click;
                void Cancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
                {
                    Host.IsOpen = false;
                    grid.Children.Remove(Host);
                }
                DialogGrid.Children.Add(Cancel);
            }
            Host.SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, "MaterialDesignEmbeddedDialogHost");
            Host.SetValue(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, 3);
            Host.SetValue(Grid.RowSpanProperty, 2);
            Host.SetValue(Panel.ZIndexProperty, 2000);
            grid.Children.Add(Host);
            Host.ShowDialog(DialogGrid);
        }
```

И вот-так долже быть вызов

```
if(Dialog()==true){
...
}
```

Comment: Вы по нормальному разрабатывать WPF проект не желаете, правильно понимаю?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А что я не так сделал?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml?view=netdesktop-5.0

Comment: @aepot Та я знаю что такое XAML. У меня динамический интерфейс.

Comment: Напишите в любом поисковике `WPF` и почитайте что это, увидите, что это некий вид проекта, в котором есть замечательная разметка стилей - XAML, а также есть классная система привязок (binding), а вы сейчас ИМХО, ерундой занимаетесь, забив на все техноголии и гвоздями прибиваете данные, стили и так далее.

Comment: Ну так вперед, привязки данных, XAML, MVVM - вот это вот всё, с самых азов. Не должно быть ни одной строчки C# кода (в идеале), взаимодействующей напрямую с контролами. Иначе вопросы такого типа вас будут преследовать вечно. А пока ответ на ваш вопрос - переписать все полностью, потому что то, что вы сделали, не поддается никакой логике.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо, если я напишу этот код на XAML, как мне узнавать на какую кнопку я нажал?

Comment: @aepot У меня должна быть разная реакция на нажатия Ок, в различных частях кода.

Comment: https://intellitect.com/material-design-in-xaml-dialog-host/

Comment: Кнопки можно прибиндить к командам, которые поменяют какое-нибудь свойство диалога. А метод, в котором стоит ожидание закрытия диалога может просто проверить значение нужного свойства. Это делается в разы проще, чем то, что я увидел в вопросе.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, попробую